# React - предупреждение You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события

Только начинаю изучать react, пробую создать список чекбоксов, в котором есть один исключающий вариант.
Т.е. при клике на него, остальные чекбоксы должны очиститься.

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: Array(this.props.answ.length).fill(false)
        }
        this.exclusive = this.props.answ.map((el) => el.excl || false)
    }
    handleClick(curr){
        const arr = this.state.checked;
        arr[curr] = !arr[curr];
        if (arr[curr]){
            for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
                if (i !== curr){
                    if (this.exclusive[curr] || (!this.exclusive[curr] && this.exclusive[i])){
                        arr[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        this.setState({
            checked: arr
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        const answ = this.props.answ.map((el, i) => {
            return (
                <div className="row_label" key={`${this.props.name}_${el.r}`}>
                    <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        name={`${this.props.name}_${el.r}`} 
                        id={`${this.props.name}_${el.r}`} 
                        value="1" 
                        checked={this.state.checked[i]}
                        onClick = {() => this.handleClick(i)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={`${this.props.name}_${el.r}`} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: el.lab }} />
                </div>
            );
        });
        return (
            <>
                {answ}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Все работает как надо, но в консоле появляется предупреждение:
Warning: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я неправильно делаю? Мне не нужно onChange.
Я могу заменить обработку onClick на onChange, тогда ошибка пропадает.
Является ли это хорошим вариантом или нужно как-то по-другому писать?

Comment: Конечно надо поменять. Например состояние чекбокса можно сменить с клавиатуры и onChange сработает, а onClick нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо! Заменила, все работает без предупреждений.
P.S. У меня onclick работает и при смене с клавиатуры 0_о. Как-то я не привыкла использовать onChange для чекбоксов.